# How to move existing web project into Laravel without changing the server hostname and route

Tags: php, laravel, web, nginx, hostname

As in the existing PHP project, there is lots of code. It'll cost some time to finish the work. So I need to keep both the project serving on the same server without change the existing API.

I config nginx like this, but it not works,both the request enter the existing_project.

```
    location ~ /biz_hq/edu/file/upload {
        root           /data/HQ/SC_Educations/hq_htdocs/existing_project/public;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/dev/shm/phpcgi.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        limit_req zone=mylimit burst=10 nodelay;
    }

    location ~ /biz_hq/edu/file/delete {
        root           /data/HQ/SC_Educations/hq_htdocs/laravel_project/public;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/dev/shm/phpcgi.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        limit_req zone=mylimit burst=10 nodelay;
    }
```